# Input text field not displaying the value inside the "quotes"

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, database

From the asp.net MVC project: I have an input text field, and its value should comes from database. But the text inside the quotes has been prevent from value.

Sample text: `Some text "150"`

But it render as: `<input type="text" id="" value="Some text" "150">`

I need to display complete text inside the quotes as input value that comes from database..!

Comment: can you update some more code? that will be easy to understand

Comment: nothing more to explain.. its just a quote problem, but i can't get the right solution!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net MVC, use @Html.Raw()
If it is plain HTML then you can combine single with double quotes.
ex. 
`<input type="text" id="" value='Some text"150"'>`

If you need a precise answer then you need to specify how your UI is being rendered.